# Monitoring tasks running on celery worker using prometheous client with SQS broker

Tags: python, celery, prometheus, amazon-sqs, background-task

So I have set up celery worker for my project with SQS as the broker. The workers are working fine. Tasks are being fetched from executed by SQS as expected. But I am unable to monitor the workers using Prometheus. None of the Prometheus metrics that I have exposed for the tasks run by celery workers are getting updated. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please add more details of your `prometheus, SQS, celery` configurations .